# How to add "selected" attribute dynamically to select option?

Tags: javascript, html-select

I have a JavaScript automated form creation formula. I'm struggling with the "selected" attribute of an option in a select list.
I'd like to have the option selected which matches the `const c` (in this case, I'd like to have the option "Formation" selected).

How can I achieve this?

```
const c = "Formation";                

const training_level = document.createElement('select');
training_level.setAttribute('value', c)
training_level.setAttribute('id', 'rec_mode')
training_level.required = true

var j = new Array("-- Type de diplôme --","Formation","Brevet","Bac","Bac +1"),    
var options = '';

for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
options += '<option value="' + j[i]+ '">' + j[i] + '</option>';
}

training_level.appendChild(options);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test if the value of `c` matches the value of `j[i]`. Use the value of that condition to fill in the `selected` attribute:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
    var selected = (c == j[i]) ? "selected" : "";
    options += '<option value="' + j[i]+ '" selected="' + selected + '">' + j[i] + '</option>';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you have an option with id **opt1** like

```
<option value="your_value" id="opt1">option text</option>
```

then you can do

```
document.getElementById('opt1').setAttribute('selected', 'selected')
```

P.S. This works only if you're using native selects. Another option is to use fake selects though